# Multiple org-mode tables sharing one #+TBLFM line

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a structured org document with tables, one for each month. Each table does the same calculations, so, the #+TBLFM line is the same in all tables.

Is there a way to force all tables share the same #+TBLFM line?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can share formulas if they're defined with emacs lisp.  Define an emacs lisp function which handles the calculations, then reference that emacs lisp function in each of the tables.  This is done in `#+TBLFM` using a quote `'` before the lisp expression.

For example,

```lisp
#+NAME: table1
| Col1 | Col2          |
|------+---------------|
|      | do stuff here |
|      |               |
|------+---------------|
#+TBLFM: @2$2='(my-shared-function)

#+NAME: table2
| Col1          | Col2 |
|---------------+------|
|               |      |
| do stuff here |      |
|---------------+------|
#+TBLFM: @3$1='(my-shared-function)

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun my-shared-function ()
  "Function to be shared between tables."
  (interactive)
  "do stuff here")
#+end_src
```

In the example, there is an emacs lisp function defined called `my-shared-function` which returns the string `"do stuff here"` (by virtue of being the return value of last expression evaluated).  Each of the table calls the function, resulting in the string being place in the indicated cell (remember that `@` is row and `$` is column).

You can read more about using emacs lisp as formulas in the manual:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-spreadsheet-lisp-formulas.html

Comment: The question was about sharing one `#+TBLFM:` line, *not* about reusing a function in different `#+TBLFM:` lines. I believe that the answer is still "no".

Comment: Fair enough, in a literal sense.  Seems like an XY problem, though.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem